# Galera cluster into Google cloud platform

Tags: sql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, galera, google-cloud-platform

We have a galera cluster with 3 nodes, on 3 different physical machines but all located in the same datacenter.

From what I understood, the reason they deployed this in the past was to increase availability and reliability.
Each node is installed on a VM using 12 cores and 4Gb RAM.

We are asked to migrate this to Google Cloup Platform in order to get rid of the ops tasks.
I could create 3 compute engine instances and deploy the galera cluster, but I have difficulties to see the added value compared to Cloud SQL instances with replication and backup. I am not very familiar in scaling heavy load systems.

The db hosted in these nodes is kind of critical and should ensure maximum availability and reliability.

What strategy should I adopt in order to migrate this architecture to GCP ?

Comment: 12 core is usually overkill, unless the queries are sloppily written.

Comment: All in same datacenter leaves you vulnerable to a DC outage.